# filtering html table using dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#mylist {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>
<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
  <option value="">ALL</option>
  <option value="fish_1">fish_1</option>
  <option value="fish_12">fish_12</option>
  <option value="chicken_1">chicken_1</option>
  <option value="chicken_12">chicken_12</option>
  <option value="fish_123">fish_123</option>
  <option value="chicken_123">chicken_123</option>
  <option value="fish">fish</option>
  <option value="chicken">chicken</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">dish</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>fish_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>fish_12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>chicken_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>chicken_12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>fish_123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>chicken_123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Description

I have been filtering my HTML table using a select tag with the index value of 1 which is the second column

### Problem

If I select fish_1 it also shows fish_1,fish_12,fish_123

### example

Filtering with the value chicken_1
Result:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Island Trading | chicken_1 |
| Koniglich Essen | chicken_12 |
| Island Trading | chicken_1 |
| Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti | chicken_123 |
| Paris specialites | chicken |

### what I need

1. if I select `chicken_1` I need to filter only `chicken_1`
2. if I select `chicken_12` I need to show only `chicken_12`, not `chicken_123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change indexOf to ===

```
 if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter) {
```

I would toggle a hide class

```
if (td) {
  tr[i].classList.toggle("hide", filter && td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() !== filter)
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      tr[i].classList.toggle("hide", filter && td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() !== filter)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#mylist {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>
<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
  <option value="">ALL</option>
  <option value="fish_1">fish_1</option>
  <option value="fish_12">fish_12</option>
  <option value="chicken_1">chicken_1</option>
  <option value="chicken_12">chicken_12</option>
  <option value="fish_123">fish_123</option>
  <option value="chicken_123">chicken_123</option>
  <option value="fish">fish</option>
  <option value="chicken">chicken</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">dish</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>fish_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>fish_12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>chicken_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>chicken_12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>fish_123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>chicken_123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It was working but how can i use two dropdown to filter table for two column

Comment: Update your question with the input and expected output. Or ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Define a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for your filter item and check exact match.

```
let filterRegex = new RegExp(`^${filter}$`)
if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().match(filterRegex)){}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      let filterRegex = new RegExp(`^${filter}$`)
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().match(filterRegex)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#mylist {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Customers</h2>
  <select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">ALL</option>
    <option value="fish_1">fish_1</option>
    <option value="fish_12">fish_12</option>
    <option value="chicken_1">chicken_1</option>
    <option value="chicken_12">chicken_12</option>
    <option value="fish_123">fish_123</option>
    <option value="chicken_123">chicken_123</option>
    <option value="fish">fish</option>
    <option value="chicken">chicken</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select>


  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">dish</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>fish_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>fish_12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>chicken_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>chicken_12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>fish_123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>chicken_123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>fish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>chicken</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, You are right. I leave it here as another solution for more complex scenarios if you don't kick me from SO :D @mplungjan

Comment: ? why would I kick you even if I had such powers?

Comment: Maybe for fun. @mplungjan

Comment: Nah. Not my kind of fun. I prefer to help people rather than ban them

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to `td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter` to display the row only on an exact match.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">ALL</option>
  <option value="fish_1">fish_1</option>
  <option value="fish_12">fish_12</option>
  <option value="chicken_1">chicken_1</option>
  <option value="chicken_12">chicken_12</option>
  <option value="fish_123">fish_123</option>
  <option value="chicken_123">chicken_123</option>
  <option value="fish">fish</option>
  <option value="chicken">chicken</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header"><th>Name</th><th>dish</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>fish_1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Berglunds snabbkop</td><td>fish_12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Island Trading</td><td>chicken_1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Koniglich Essen</td><td>chicken_12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td><td>fish_123</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>chicken_123</td></tr>
  <tr><td>North/South</td><td>fish</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Paris specialites</td><td>chicken</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. indexOf() returns -1 if the value is not found.
When you use indexof it will found "fish" in the String and direct return the occurrence of fish ..

**Try to check condition on whole String**

```
 if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter) { Your Code }
```